# How do I enable the splash screen on dm 365 during uboot?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, splash-screen, u-boot

I am using a custom davinci board running Arago project. I am using analog video out (PAL), and though the OLED display powers on with uboot, no image comes till the kernel has finished loading. I want to display a logo as soon as uboot starts and display powers on. I tried adding
`#define CONFIG_SPLASH_SCREEN` 
in the uboot config file, but that doesn't work.
One approach I can think of is to put an image in the NAND memory, and then use the
`setenv splashimage <address>`
 command to display it during uboot. But the problem is, I do not know how to put the image in the NAND memory in a particular address.
Alternative methods are also welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONFIG_SPLASH_SCREEN` only tells U-Boot to include the code required for supporting splash screens.  It says absolutely nothing about *how* to display the splash screen or *where* to find it.  It only provides you with helpful functionality to achieve that goal.

There is no need to put your image at a specific address in NAND.  If your U-Boot can access the filesystem, you could just have the image in a file.  You could also embed the image in the U-Boot image if you like.  That's entirely up to you.  The functionality included by the `CONFIG_SPLASH_SCREEN` will help you load an image from any number of sources.

The trick is getting it displayed.  You'll need to teach U-Boot enough about your graphics hardware to get the image out.  On most SoCs, that's just a matter of setting up the framebuffer, loading your image into it, and telling the hardware to start clocking it out.

It doesn't look like someone has written a framebuffer driver for the DM365, so you'll have to do that yourself.  Or maybe ask on the mailing list if anyone has done it but not contributed it back yet.  If you have to do the work yourself, it's probably easiest to start from the Linux driver and port only the bits you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find [here](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootSplashScreen) the official documentation for u-boot's splash. It has an example on how to load the file into nand, using tftp.

Find [here](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/SystemSetup#Section_4.6.) how to set the tftp server in case you don't already have.

Comment: I do have a tftp server running. But when I write `tftp 100000 /tftpboot/denx_startup.bmp`, I get an error `100000: unknown host`, followed by `tftp>`. Could you please help me with this? Also, isn't this for LCD display? (I am using PAL). Thanks!